# 25 Oct read as "25" or "25th"?

Tags: pronunciation, reading-aloud

I hear some people read days in names as non-ordinal numbers. Not sure if that is correct.

For example,  25 October is read as "twenty five October" or "twenty fifth October"? Or both?

I am looking for official rule, not slang or casual talk.

Comment: "25 October", "October 25", "October twenty-fifth", and "the 25th of October" are all valid ways to say this date. The first one ("25 October") is probably least common, but it is used in some contexts (for example, the U.S. military often uses this format for dates, both in written and pronounced forms).

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware this was a duplicate. Sorry

Comment: No need for an apology! With 12,000 questions (and counting!) it might be hard to find the older question.